Normals from Blender to unity
Hello all
I'm serializing geometry from blender and getting the vertices, indicies, normals, uv's etc. I then recreate in Unity with those values. Everything is going well, but I cannot get the normals to look right. I'm transforming them to matrix_world together with the vertices, but they still look wrong.
This is how I get and treat the normals when finding them:
            for vertice in mesh.vertices:
               worldVertice = obj.matrix_world @ vertice.co
               meshVertice.extend([worldVertice.x,worldVertice.y,worldVertice.z])

               worldNormal = obj.matrix_world @ vertice.normal
               meshNormal.extend([worldNormal.x,worldNormal.y,worldNormal.z])

In Unity I take into account the different coordinate system so it's not that.
This is what the geometry looks like in Unity (just a simple box from Blender). Everything is fine except the normals creating these strange surface artefacts. Anybody how to correct this when fetching the information about them? Then I can stop going in circles.


Hello, this look like a Unity problem rather than Blender problem. Most likely there is a setting in Unity to draw faces as "flat-shaded" and not smooth shaded.

BTW I would normalize the normals after applying matrix_world because if your object is scaled your normal will come out with a length < or > 1. In fact I think you only need to apply the object rotation to the normal, not the translation, since a normal doesn't have an origin point, only a direction.

Thanks @Gorgious There is nothing in the shader that is off. It's just a simple standard shader. I tried doing this instead:
worldNormal = obj.rotation_euler.to_matrix() @ vertice.normal
It changes the appearance of the surface, but not to the better... I slo tried the normalize, but nothing changes. I just can't get it right.

Doing an EdgeSplit modifier (creating edges) on the object created the correct normals for recreating in Unity
